# How to undo specific line in vim?

Tags: vim

I have lots of modifications in a file, but I want to undo specific line to initial state which keep other lines at current state.

Is there a way to do it in vim?

Comment: See [VIM:: Undo changes on or around the specified text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5585499/477035) and also [Undo branches](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_undo_branches).

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in way to undo a line.

What I usually do is to undo `u` until I am at the changes I want to keep, copy the line or block of text and then do a `:e!` to reset the file and paste the changes.

A great plugin that I use for more complex changes is [Undo Tree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree)